# Not Found (Java Servlet)

Tags: java, servlets

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Currency Converter</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Currency Converter</h1>

<HR>

<form method=get action="http://localhost:8080/logan_jahnke_currency/app/Converter">

<P>Enter your amount of money is US Dollars below (do not include the dollar sign)

<P>For example: <tt>20</tt>

<P>Input amount in dollars: <INPUT NAME="dollars" TYPE=text size=50>

<select name="currency">
 <option value="USD">United States Dollar</option>
 <option value="ARS">Argentinean Peso</option>
 <option value="AUD">Australian Dollar</option>
 <option value="BRL">Brazilian Real</option>
 <option value="GBP">British Pound</option>
 <option value="CAD">Canadian Dollar</option>
 <option value="CLP">Chilean Peso</option>
 <option value="CNY">Chinese YuanRenminbi</option>
 <option value="CZK">Czech Koruna</option>
 <option value="DKK">Danish Krone</option>
</select>

<P><P><P><INPUT TYPE=submit> <INPUT TYPE=reset>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML File ^

XML File V

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
version="2.4">

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>converter</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>logan_jahnke_currency.Converter</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>converter</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/converter</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Directory:

```
app
   converter.html
   WEB-INF
      classes
         logan_jahnke_currency
            Converter.class
      lib
         *.jar
      web.xml
```

My initial HTML works fine at the address: http://localhost:8080/logan_jahnke_currency/app/converter.html

However, when I press submit, I get "Not Found".

Anyone see the problem? I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Problem in title "Not Found" :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your posted servlet mapping, this

```
action="http://localhost:8080/logan_jahnke_currency/app/Converter"
```

Assuming your application root context is `logan_jahnke_currency` then it should be

```
action="http://localhost:8080/logan_jahnke_currency/converter"
```

because you have

```
<url-pattern>/converter</url-pattern>
```

in your mapping.

Comment: I've tried this and I still get "Not Found"

Comment: Are you packaging your application into a war file? What **exactly** have you tried? What is your root application path, and where does `app` fit in your tree?

Comment: I package the `app` directory into a war file, which contains everything listed above.

Comment: WEB-INF has to be in the root of your war. `./WEB-INF`, not `./app/WEB-INF`.